# Server is not shutting down gracefully due to concurrency malpractice

Tags: java, concurrency, grizzly

I have a simple server based on Grizzly NIO. I'm starting/shutting it down it as follows, please notice the comment near the shutdown method:

```
public class MyServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create("someURL"), resourceConfig, false);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            server.shutdownNow();
        }));

        server.start();
        Thread.currentThread().join();
        server.shutdown(); //this line is never reached
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
        //exception handling
    }
}
}
```

When I terminate the server it immediately gets shutdown since the server.shutdown() line is never reached instead of a graceful manner. Being that said, I tried to implement a shutdown hook but its not being called either. I'm suspecting of my join() implementation but not sure about it. Any help to achieve a graceful shutdown would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.currentThread().join()` is going to block forever. It is waiting for itself to finish but can't finish because it's waiting for itself to finish.

Comment: would you suggest a correct mechanism to handle it?

Comment: @johndoe I don't see why you have that in there at all. You're running in main, there is no need for the join.

Comment: since it's a server implementation, I'm using the API of Grizzly, I'm starting it then want to shut it down gracefully.

Comment: @johndoe Then just remove the `join` call? Or are you wanting to wait until Grizzly is finished? Perhaps take a look at this: https://javaee.github.io/grizzly/httpserverframework.html